# Instalação webstorm no ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, webstorm

Não consigo instalar o webstorm no ubuntu, já baixei no site e etc mas não consigo instalar, alguém sabe instalar via terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entra na pasta do WebStorm, depois entra dentro da pasta bin, depois executa o seguinte comando `sudo ./webstorm.sh`, apos isso ele vai abrir um wizard na interface gráfica e é só next, next e finish.

Obs: caso de algum problema na hora da execução do script pode ser algo relacionado a permicionamento do arquivo `webstorm.sh` ai basta você executar um `chmod +x webstorm.sh` antes.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: Beleza, que bom que ajudou, se possível marque a resposta como util também :D